# Как передать С++ поинтер в Java (нужно для Unity)?

Tags: java, c++, unity3d

Предисловие : мне нужно получить картинку в Unity C# из Java/C++ библиотеки.

У меня есть С++ либа которая делает декодинг и как результат возвращает картинку width, height и ptr data.

```cpp
int width = m_manager->getModel()->GetTexture().GetWidth();
int height = m_manager->getModel()->GetTexture().GetHeight();
unsigned char const * data = m_manager->getModel()->GetTexture().GetDataPtr();
```

Мне нужно передать эту дату в JNI для того, что передать ее дальше в Unity. С высотой и шириной проблем нет, но я не совсем понимаю, как передать `unsigned char const * data` из managed (C++) кода в unmanaged (Java)?

То есть путь который я выбрал выглядит так `Unity C# plugin -> JNI -> native c++` я не уверен, что это должно быть так.

Comment: Отформатируйте код

Comment: Да, у вас куча пробелов перед кодом

Comment: Нет, у вас есть кнопка "править"

Comment: Можно переделать как jlong. Но а почему бы не предавать сразу в C++ плагин? чем меньше интеропа, тем лучше.